# Dynamic Drop Down(select box) in JQGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid, mvcjqgrid

i'm trying to build simple selectbox insdie my jqgrid cell with select options, i looked alot over the past few days , but most answers just don't get me there here my js code :

```
   $('#ImageModel').html( '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" class="display" id="example"></table>' );
   $("#example").jqGrid({ //set your grid id
       url: GlobalConfig.clientMangerUrl,
       datatype: 'json',
       styleUI : 'Bootstrap',
colNames:['Image Name','Image Path','myname'], //define column names
colModel:[
{name:'ImageName', key: true},
{name:'ImagePath'}, 
 {name:'Rois', edittype:'select'},//****i tried alot but nothing works i just dont know, Rois is a string array** 
],** 
//pager: '#ImageModel', //set your pager div id
caption:"jqGrid Example", //title of grid    

});
```

i getting something like this :
[image]

Comment: can you please upload you code with plunker or fiddle

Comment: Sorry, but it's not full clear what you want to implement. jqGrid provides three main editing modes (inline editing, form editing and cell editing). The grid will be displays by default **with texts** without any selects, checkboxes or other *editing* elements. It allows the user use sorting, paging, filtering or searching in the data which will be displayed. On click on some button (in the row or on the toolbar) or just on click/double-click on the row one can *start editing* of the row or the cell. During editing the used uses controls like selects to change the data and can save the changes